Configuration Setting "createemptyblocks" in genesis.json Removes Itself Upon Network Restart
I am creating a Hyperledger Besu network and configuring the consensus algorithm as Clique. I added "createemptyblocks": false to my genesis.json configuration to stop the creation of empty blocks. My configuration looks like this:
"config": {
    "chainId": 1337,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "zeroBaseFee": true,
    "clique": {
        "blockperiodseconds": 15,
        "epochlength": 30000,
        "createemptyblocks": false
    }
},
// more ...

However, after restarting the network, the "createemptyblocks": false setting is removed from genesis.json.
how can I ensure that the "createemptyblocks": false setting is retained after a network restart?
I want to stop creating empty blocks.
